# How to compare all values stored in array-table between two foreign key values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL database in 1NF with the following tables:

```
sandwich_id  |  sandwich_name  | sandwich_price
_______________________________________________
0            |  BLT            |  5.5
1            |  Reuben         |  7.0
3            |  Grilled Cheese |  3.75
...
```

and a separate table that stores all the ingredient values:

```
sandwich_id |  ingredient
__________________________
0           |  bacon
0           |  lettuce
0           |  tomato
1           |  corned beef
1           |  swiss cheese
...
```

How can I compare all the sandwiches by their ingredients to determine which are the most similar?

(Also, is there a technical term for that second table that I'm missing? I want to call it a map table, but I know that's not quite right, since a map table stores foreign keys for two tables and this one's more of an offshoot of the first...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sw1.sandwich_name, sw2.sandwich_name, COUNT(i1.ingredient) as [Ingredients in common]
from sandwiches sw1
join sandwiches sw2 on sw2.sandwich_id < sw1.sandwich_id
join ingredients i1 on i1.sandwich_id = sw1.sandwich_id
where exists (select 1
                from sandwiches sw
                join ingredients i on i.sandwich_id = sw.sandwich_id
               where i.ingredient = i1.ingredient
                 and sw.sandwich_id = sw2.sandwich_id)
group by sw1.sandwich_name, sw2.sandwich_name
order by [Ingredients in common] desc, sw1.sandwich_name, sw2.sandwich_name
```